# Unable to open Grakn Visualizer on Windows

Tags: python, windows, vaticle-typedb

I am new to grakn. I have installed Grakn 1.5.6 on Windows 10 , with Python Grakn, and Grakn Client API. I am able to start the Grakn server and create the schema. I was also able to insert data to the schema using Python API.

I am not able to open the Visualizer from localhost:4567. I couldn't find the grakn-engine.properties file where they say we can change the port.
Please guide me if anyone has faced the same problem and able to resolve. Is there any config change which i may need to do, to get the grakn Visualizer.
Thanks
SS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grakn does not have a web visualiser anymore.

You can use Grakn Workbase https://github.com/graknlabs/workbase/releases
to explore your data and design you schema visually.

You can find the config file in `server/conf/grakn.properties` now.

Comment: Thanks for the Solution. Yes I was able to install grakn workbase and connect to my schema